# Is it possible to key a single sort on multiple fields in MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, sorting

I have a simple music database that contains information about CDs (Artist, Album Title, Release Year, etc.). Basically, I want to sort my query by Artist, then Release Year (which is easy to do) but in the case where a CD does not have an Artist, I would like the sort to key on the Album Title.

As an example, for the following CDs:

```
> db.music.find()
{ "_id" : ObjectId("581d3e073a4d1f0d73a8650b"), "Type" : "CD", "Artist" : "Korn", "Title" : "Korn", "ReleaseYear" : 1994 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("581d3e283a4d1f0d73a8650c"), "Type" : "CD", "Artist" : "Korn", "Title" : "Life is Peachy", "ReleaseYear" : 1996 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("581d3efd3a4d1f0d73a8650d"), "Type" : "CD", "Title" : "Big Daddy", "ReleaseYear" : 1999 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("581d3f3c3a4d1f0d73a8650e"), "Type" : "CD", "Title" : "Aerosmith", "ReleaseYear" : 1973, "Artist" : "Aerosmith" }
```

I would want it sorted into:

```
Aerosmith - Aerosmith (1973)
Big Daddy (1999)
Korn - Korn (1994)
Korn - Life is Peachy (1996)
```

Here is what I have tried:

```
> db.music.find().sort({[Artist:1,Title:1],ReleaseYear:1})
2016-11-04T22:10:39.317-0400 E QUERY    [thread1] SyntaxError: missing ] in computed property name @(shell):1:29
> db.music.find().sort({[Artist,Title]:1,ReleaseYear:1})
2016-11-04T22:10:50.564-0400 E QUERY    [thread1] SyntaxError: missing ] in computed property name @(shell):1:29
> db.music.find().sort({{Artist:1,Title:1},ReleaseYear:1})
2016-11-04T22:11:12.040-0400 E QUERY    [thread1] SyntaxError: invalid property id @(shell):1:22
```

I *COULD* put in a `SortName` field that contains either the Artist or the Title, but would like to avoid putting that into the document directly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the sorting to be efficient on large data sets and you serve the query in OLTP-style workloads, a materialized sorting key is your best choice, as you can put an index for sorting on it. The MongoDB sort operator does not natively support ad-hoc, user-defined sort keys.

If it is okay for the query to consume more time, e.g. for analytics, you can employ MongoDB's [**aggregation framework**](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/aggregation/), in particular, the two operators:

- [$project](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/reference/operator/aggregation/project/) which allows the creation of new fields in the aggregation pipeline
- [$ifNull](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/ifNull) that returns a non-null value (first argument) or a fallback expression (second argument)

Using those, your sort query can be written as:

```js
db.music.aggregate([
  { $project:
    { "Artist": 1,
      "Title": 1,
      "ReleaseYear": 1,
      "SortName": { "$ifNull" : [ "$Artist", "$Title" ] },
    }
  },
  { $sort: { "SortName": 1, "ReleaseYear": 1} }
]);
```

You can add any additional [pipeline steps](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation-pipeline/) to this, for example, to first filter the data (`$match`).

Comment: This is great! I'm afraid there's a small error somewhere. I get `A pipeline stage specification object must contain exactly one field.` If I take out the `, $sort: {}` I get the right dataset with the new field `SortName`.

Comment: Ah, it looks like the `$project` and `$sort` need to be separate elements in the aggregate array. With that it works perfectly!